# Unable to change servername after VM Clone

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, instance

For reasons out of my control I must find a solution to this issue. Simply reinstalling the instance is not an option. The server name that appears as server_id 0 in sys.servers is still showing the old servername.

I'm getting an error when running the below command:

```
sp_dropserver 'OLD_INSTANCE'
GO
sp_addserver 'NEW_INSTANCE', Local
GO
```

Error message:

> Msg 15190, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropserver, Line 67
>   
> There are still remote logins or linked logins for the server 'OLD_INSTANCE'.
>   
> Msg 15028, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addserver, Line 87
>   
> The server 'NEW_INSTANCE' already exists.

The strangest thing is, the remote login is a 'null' login.

```
exec sp_dropremotelogin @remoteserver = 'OLD_INSTANCE'
go
```

Error message:

> Msg 15185, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dropremotelogin, Line 70
>   
> There is no remote user '(null)' mapped to local user '(null)' from the remote server 'OLD_INSTANCE'.

No logins exist for the old instance.

```
sp_helpremotelogin 'OLD_INSTANCE'
```

> Msg 15201, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helpremotelogin, Line 37
>   
> There are no remote logins for the remote server 'OLD_INSTANCE'.

How do I rename this instance if I can't drop the non-existing login? Is there a way to flush the logins?

Comment: What do you see from `SELECT * FROM sys.linked_logins WHERE server_id = 0;`? (In other words, the error message says "remote logins or linked logins" and you only checked for remote logins.)

Comment: You're right. The linked_login exists. What is the command for getting rid of this login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check both `sys.remote_logins` and `sys.linked_logins`. You should be able to build a script dynamically to drop the set you find:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'EXEC sys.sp_droplinkedsrvlogin @s, N''' + remote_name + N''''
  FROM sys.linked_logins
  WHERE server_id = 0 AND remote_name IS NOT NULL;

SELECT @sql += N'EXEC sys.sp_dropremotelogin @s, N''' + remote_name + N''''
  FROM sys.remote_logins
  WHERE server_id = 0 AND remote_name IS NOT NULL;

PRINT @sql; -- spot check will only show first 8K of command

DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(512) = N'old server name';
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@s NVARCHAR(512)', N'.\SQL2014';
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to post, because this gave me the most help today in renaming a SQL2014 default instance...

You can also use the following:

```
exec sp_dropserver 'current_name', @droplogins = 'droplogins'
exec sp_addserver 'new_name', local
```

This absolutely saved my bacon today. Thank you for this post, and I hope that mine can help others, also.

Context: had a failover from SQL2008 to a new installation of SQL2014. There are a few production SQL machines that are linked as per our software provider's specs.

I was trying to rename the 2014 server to match the IP and name of the 2008 server (already changed to something different), but kept getting the error for remote/linked logins existing.

After a LOT of searching, the @droplogins command worked.

I hope this helps someone in the future.